# Connecting 5 tables but excluding values from the 5th

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

#### Data tables

I got 5 tables with certain values:

1. Table: `tbl_1`

```
+-------+-------+
| nm_id | name  |
+-------+-------+
|     1 | name1 |
|     2 | name2 |
|     3 | name3 |
+-------+-------+
```

2. Table: `tbl_2`

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|post_id| nm_id | post  |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 | text1 |
|     2 |     1 | text2 |
|     3 |     2 | text3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

3. Table: `tbl_3`

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|com_id |post_id| nm_id | com   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |     1 | text1 |
|     2 |     2 |     1 | text2 |
|     3 |     2 |     2 | text3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

4. Table: `tbl_4`

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|com2_id|com_id||post_id| nm_id | com2  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |     1 |     1 | text1 |
|     2 |     2 |     2 |     1 | text2 |
|     3 |     1 |     2 |     2 | text3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

5. Table: `tbl_5`

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|rep_id |com2_id|com_id||post_id| nm_id | text  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |  null |     1 |     1 |     1 | text1 |
|     2 |  null |  null |     1 |     1 | text2 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

#### What I tried

I need to get all the values, but the idea is to **exclude values from `tbl_5`** from result. So far what I do is:

1. select `tbl_2` then join `tbl_1` on `nm_id` then exclude `tbl_5` on `post_id` -> **1stVariable**

```
SELECT tbl_2.*, name.tbl_1
FROM tbl_2
INNER JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_1.nm_id = tbl_2.nm_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_5 ON tbl_2.post_id = tbl_5.post_id
WHERE tbl_2.post_id = *variable* AND tbl_5.rep_id IS NULL
```

2. select `tbl_3` then join `tbl_2` on `com_id` then join `tbl_1` on `nm_id` exclude `tbl_5` on `com_id` -> **2ndVariable**

```
SELECT tbl_3.*, name.tbl_1
FROM tbl_3
INNER JOIN tbl_3 ON tbl_1.nm_id = tbl_3.nm_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_5 ON tbl_3.com_id = tbl_5.com_id
WHERE tbl_3.com_id = *variable* AND tbl_5.rep_id IS NULL
```

3. select `tbl_4` then join `tbl_1` on `nm_id` exclude `tbl_5` on `com2_id` -> **3rdVariable**

```
SELECT tbl_4.*, name.tbl_1
FROM tbl_4
INNER JOIN tbl_4 ON tbl_1.nm_id = tbl_4.nm_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_5 ON tbl_4.com2_id = tbl_5.com2_id
WHERE tbl_4.com2_id = *variable* AND tbl_5.rep_id IS NULL
```

#### My current output is JSON

```
{
  post:{...},
  com:{...},
  com2:{...}
}
```

#### Needed JSON output

What happens is that my .js gets so long and complicated with 3 separated arrays. I was trying to get everything within 1st variable, what i can't understand is how to get array within array:

```
{
   post: {
     post_id: "post_id",
     name: "name",
     com: {
       com_id:"com_id",
       com:"com",
       name:"name",
       com2:{
         com2_id:"com2_id",
         com2:"com2",
         name:"name",
         }
      },
   }
}
```

I really hope this is understandable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show data as text and not as image

Comment: I'm very sorry but this is the only way i know how to show correctly. Just joined today... i will try to edit.

Comment: You should invest time in proper formatting of your post. This leads to better chances for an answer. I added some formatting examples to your post. Format your tables as __ASCII-table__ so you can embed them as text, for example: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: @hc_dev I hope that formatting is right this time, thanks for the help in that regard!

Comment: @Djisin Well formatted. Most SO members require to show your attempts by posting code as [example], so you could __add your SQL__ to the preformatted code-block  (otherwise delete my SELECT-example, since it does not reflect your case).

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a query like this:

```
select . . .    -- columns you want
from . . .      -- joins among the first four tables
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_5 t5
                  where . . .    -- conditions that match table 5 to the other tables
                 );
```

I can speculate that your conditions are something like:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_5 t5
                  where t5.com_id = t4.com_id and
                        t5.post_id = t2.post_id and
                        t5.nm_id = t1.nm_id
                 )
```

but your question is not clear on how the tables are matched.

Comment: I have updated the question once more, i hope it it more clear now